# Pinnacle Studio Codecs

Tags: video-editing, codec

I'm having problems importing TV recordings into Pinnacle Studio 12 on Windows Vista. My STB records TS files. I believe the Australian digital standard is to use MP4 but I'm not certain. I have tried converting into WMV and AVI but it still doesn't work (closest I've gotten is getting the video in but no sound). Installing codec packs do not make a difference either. The converted files play well in Media Player but Studio doesn't want to know. How do I get Studio to recognise the TS files or what kind of other file are compatable with the Studio codecs?